# Get a part from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input field with this name:

`myinput[something][etc]`

How can I get the contents from the last `[]` part from it? i.e. `etc` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match whatever is in between the last pair of `[]`. Because `[` and `]` have special meaning in regexp (they are used to delimit character classes), you have to escape them with `\`. The entire match (aside from the `[` and the `]`) is anchored at the end of the string using `$`.

```
var s = 'myinput[something][etc]',
    re = /\[([^\]]*)\]$/
    text = re.exec(s)[1]; // "etc"
```

Comment: +1 - I envy people like you who can pull regex solutions out of a hat.

Comment: @Alien this one is super simple, honestly. It just looks ugly because there's a lot of escaping.

Comment: I suppose once I actually get around to "learning it" I'll agree haha. Until then, props, sir :)

Answer (score 6):

If you know that the string ends with the `]`, you can use simple string operations:

```
var name = "myinput[something][etc]";
var index = name.lastIndexOf('[');
var last = name.substr(index + 1, name.length - index - 2);
```

Comment: +1 for a solution 3X faster than the regex one:  http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-lastindexof

Comment: @AlienWebguy: It's 6 times faster in IE, and 15 times faster in Firefox. :)

Comment: wow that's something to be said about [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) - That benchmark shows IE9 running the lastindexof more than twice as fast as Chrome. Say it ain't so!

Comment: @AlienWebguy: The Chrome tests are run on slower computers. When I run it, IE 9 is only 50% faster.